# c# to MACosx mono lost reference to resources

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin

I ported my Visual C# project to MACosx using mono with Xamarin studio, but I'm missing the references to images and icons only.

I carefully changed every namespace in the project, but when I call this in Mainwindow.designer.cs:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = global::MonoSync.Properties.Resources.foo_2;
```

Throws this error:

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "namespace.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "gnegne" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

if I go to the Resources.designer.cs:

```
    internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap foo_2 {
        get {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("foo_2", resourceCulture);
            return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
        }
    }
```

what is happening?

Comment: Check the build action for the resource is set to EmbeddedResource. I would also take a look at your compiled assembly using an application such as ILSpy http://ilspy.net/ and see what the full name of the embedded resources are in your assembly. The error message suggests the name of the embedded resource does not match what the code is looking for. Or the resources are not embedded.

Comment: Hi thank you for the fast response, but I'm on MacOSx and I cannot use ilSpy...

Comment: On the Mac try using "monodis --presources YourAssemblyFilename". That will show the names of the embedded resources.